# jquery get value from a select tag and use it in a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown select that I need to get the value from and put it inside the glassCode variable. I can get the value and display it on an alert box inside the change event. But, when I try to use it outside the change event I get nothing.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <select id="glassProduct">
        <option value="GI032">GI032 CLEAR FLOAT 3.2MM</option>
        <option value="GI040">GI040 CLEAR FLOAT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

The Jquery:

```
$("#glassProduct").change(function(){
    var glassCode=$(this).val();
    alert(glassCode);//this gives me the code
});//end of on change glassProduct

$("#calculate").click(function(){
    console.log("glass code: " +glassCode);//this gives me the same all the time
});
```

Comment: You need to save glassCode to a global or other variable within the scope of your JS file.  Here the glassCode variable is within the change scope, so when you log it in your click event you will not get the new value

Answer (score 2):

I think you should know about the Scope and Scope Chain of Javascript

[Understanding Scope and Context in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

the problem of your code is that the `glassCode` in `change` is not in the same scope with the one in `click`,although they have the same name.

so the Jquery should be

```
var glassCode; // share the same scope in two function
$("#glassProduct").change(function(){
    glassCode=$(this).val();
    alert(glassCode);
});

$("#calculate").click(function(){
    console.log("glass code: " +glassCode);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to use glassCode variable in global scope, there is no need to store it, just use Jquery selected in order to get select selected value:

```
    var glasscode;
    $("#calculate").click(function(){
      glasscode=$('#glassProduct option:selected').text()
      alert(glasscode);
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4hhs5Lnf/)

Comment: yeah, thanks but I needed to get stored. I need to get that code in the on change event. So later I can do something with that code

Comment: If you need this value during your function execution, just store in in local, global or prototype variable. See my updated answer with local variable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Within the callback function, you declare `var glassCode=$(this).val()` which is a local variable. "Local" in this case refers to the callback function itself. That is also to say that the variable is out-of-scope from outside of this function.

To access glassCode from within another function, like the click handler, you need to define it on some object with global scope. The most straightforward way would be to define it on the global `window` object. However, this is generally frowned upon because it's easy to clutter the top-level object with many individual variables. The workaround is to use a namespace specific to your application. Consider this instead:

```
$("#glassProduct").change(function(){
  glass = window.glass || {};
  glass.glassCode=$(this).val();
  alert(glassCode);
});//end of on change glassProduct

$("#calculate").click(function(){
  console.log("glass code: " +window.glass.glassCode);
});
```

Comment: Rick, what is that || is that or?? on glass= window.glass ||{};

Comment: It uses window.glass if it exists, otherwise it initializes window.glass to an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<select id="glassProduct">
<option value="GI032">GI032 CLEAR FLOAT 3.2MM</option>
<option value="GI040">GI040 CLEAR FLOAT</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
var glassCode;

$("#glassProduct").change(function(){
 glassCode=$(this).val();
        alert(glassCode);
//this gives me the code
});//end of on change glassProduct

$("#calculate").click(function(){

console.log("glass code: " +glassCode);//this gives me the same all the time
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shilpa26/f7m94x9x/

Comment: when I go to the fiddle, I open firebug, nothing shows up in the console, thanks yfor your reply